# Solving 'WriteBinaryData can only be called when State is Value, not when State is Name' when serializing nested objects

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to solve an exception related to serializing nested objects using 2 different serializers.

This is a simplified version of my classes and how I'm implementing it:

```
public class NestedClass
{
    int Number  { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class ParentClass
{
    IReadonlyCollection<NestedClass> Numbers;
    
    public IReadOnlyCollection<T> ToList()
    {
       return Numbers;
    }
}
```

```
public class NestedClassSerializer<T> : SerializerBase<NestedClass>
{
    public override void Serialize(
        BsonSerializationContext ctx, 
        BsonSerializationArgs args, 
        NestedClass nestedClass)
    {
        // If I uncomment this line we'll get a similar exception already in this stage:
        // WriteStartDocument can only be called when State is Initial or Value or ScopeDocument or Done, not when State is Name.
        //ctx.Writer.WriteStartDocument();
        
        // 'WriteBinaryData can only be called when State is Value, not when State is Name' 
        // exception occurs here !
        BsonSerializer.Serialize(ctx.Writer, nestedClass.X);
        
        //ctx.Writer.WriteEndDocument();
    }
}
```

```
public class ParentClassSerializer<T> : SerializerBase<T>
{
    // 'ItemSerializer' is initialzied as 'NestedClassSerializer' which was registered as required.
    private static readonly IBsonSerializer<T> ItemSerializer = BsonSerializer.LookupSerializer<T>();

    public override void Serialize(
        BsonSerializationContext ctx, 
        BsonSerializationArgs args, 
        T parentClass)
    {
        ctx.Writer.WriteStartDocument();

        var list = parentClass.ToList();
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            // Calling NestedClassSerializer.
            ItemSerializer.Serialize(ctx, args, item);
        }

        ctx.Writer.WriteEndDocument();
    }
}
```

I get the above mentioned exception when executing the **ItemSerializer.Serialize(ctx, args, item)** line.
As written above I'll get a similar exception if I execute the currently-commented **ctx.Writer.WriteStartDocument()** line.

In both cases, the problem is with the **BsonSerializationContext** that is being passed from **ParentClassSerializer** to **NestedClassSerializer**; I checked its **State** property value and it is indeed *Name* because of the **ctx.Writer.WriteStartDocument()** in the start of **ParentClassSerializer.Serialize**.

What weird to me is that the above isn't a complicated code or scenario, so maybe I have a basic misunderstanding of how to perform the serialization and I'll be happy to get any help on this.

**Note: I reviewed a lot of related questions but couldn't find a similar case.**

Comment: What purpose does `NestedClassSerializer` have? Typically, serializers will handle properties just fine on their own, but there is sometimes a requirement of public setter/getter and 'simple' collection types, i.e. you might want to declare your numbers as `public NestedClass[] Numbers {get;set;}`

Comment: @JonasH First, thanks for your comment. In my original code, `Numbers` is a readonly field which can be fetched only using the `ToList` method. Moroever, it is actually a more complicated object for which I want to have my own serializer. In addition, `ParentClass` can include additional complicated **custom** objects and I'm trying to understand if my above code (i.e. calling a one serializer from a second serializer), is correct or not or maybe the above isn't supported which seems very strong to me as how do we serialize a class with complicated custom properties? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The approach I have used for 'special' cases is, 1. Use a separate DTO type just for serialization. 2. Serialize the inner object to a `byte[]` or string, that is stored in the outer DTO object.

Comment: @JonasH Thanks. If I understand correctly, in the custom serializer of my **outer** object, I should get either a `byte[]` or a JSON string and perform the actual writing myself? For example: `ctx.Writer.WriteName("myInnerDtoName"); ctx.Writer.WriteString("<myInnerDtoNameJsonString>");`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming classes

```
public class NestedClass
{
    public int Number  { get; set; }
}
public class Parent
{
    public NestedClass Nested { get; set; }
}
```

With the assumption that NestedClass is a placeholder for something much more complicated. I would create DTO class(es)

```
public class NestedClassDTO{
    public int Number {get;set;}
    public NestedClassDTO(NestedClass n) => Number = n.Number;
}
public class ParentDTO{
    public byte[] Nested {get;set;}
    public NestedClassDTO(byte[] nested) => Nested = nested;
}
```

And serialize this like

```
var parent = new Parent();
using var nestedMs = new MemoryStream();
mySerializer.Serialize(nestedMs, parent.Nested);
var parentDto = new ParentDto(nestedMs.ToArray());
using var parentMs = new MemoryStream();
mySerializer.Serialize(parentMs, parentDto);
```

I.e. you first serialize the nested DTO object to a memory stream, and then assign the memory stream to your parentDTO object and serialize that. This assume you have a serializer that takes a stream and a object, this seem to be fairly common, even if Json.Net seem to require you to wrap the stream in a streamWriter and jsonTestWriter. But I'm not familiar with your particular serialization library, so it might work in some different way.

Using separate DTO classes can help in case you need attributes to help the serializer, and if you make more radical changes to the datastructure that is difficult for the serializer to cope with.

If it is a good idea to use a nested object in this way is another issue. In general I would say no, but there might be some special cases where it might be motivated.

Comment: Thank you for this effort !